# limiting access to a report

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2000

- I'm doing a report using **PHP** and **SQL SERVER 2000**
- In this report, PHP page is accessing a live database with lot of
     processes happening.
- The problem i'm facing is, when i give this report to users they
     frequently access the report and it can cause havoc to the daily
     processes.
- I want to limit the access time for a given day to some number(let's
     say 10 times per day) or between two hours periods per person(once accessed a person only can view the report after 2
  hours).
- Is this achievable via PHP? or do i need to do it in SQL SERVER 2000
     configurations?
- Please provide me with a detailed answer with the references if
     possible

Comment: When you say "report," do you mean SSRS, or is this some custom report you generate via PHP code?

Comment: It is a custom report done using PHP

Comment: Ah, then likely @Jakub's answer is best. Also, this may be a good read: http://www.sitepoint.com/caching-php-performance/

Answer (score 1):

You quite simply enable/create caching, so the report is generated a few times a day (either a cronjob / time generation) or by user activation, then allow that report to 'live' for a few hours (or whatever your parameters are).

Basically you need to create some caching PHP side. I would create a copy of the report then send that to users, and update it throughout the day without their interaction.

**UPDATE**
A quick example I found: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Output-Caching-with-PHP/